# View files in app's filesystem for iOS for testing?

Tags: ios, filesystems

I am working on an app right now that is supposed to generate a text document from an NSString , save it to the app's documents foldr, and then upload it to the iCloud.

I want to check and see if the file is actually being created and saved in the Documents folder in my app's Sandbox.

> How do you look at the files saved on an iPhone? (Either on the phone
>   or when it is connected via USB to my Mac.)

This is just for testing purposes and all I want to do is view the file name and contents, not edit them in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to pdesantis's answer, you can achieve what you want through Xcode rather than relying on third-party tools. Open the Organiser, select the Devices tab, select Applications under the relevant device in the column on the left, then select the app you're interested in in the large area on the right and click Download at the bottom of the screen to grab its current local storage.

Comment: Ah that is much easier. I changed the accepted answer to your's because I think this is the more appropriate solution for people who will view this question in the future. (Although, the third party option by pdesantis is still a very good option as well).

Answer (score 2):

Try this
http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/